# Autohotkey alter Mouse button

Tags: keyboard, mouse, autohotkey

I've been trying to learn how to make this script on Autohotkey but gotta say their documentation is the complete opposite of noob-friendly and I can't seem to find any similar example either.

I'll try to describe what I intend: When A is pressed on the keyboard (if was PRESSED, not held down), change the RButton to behave as the LButton until I click it, which then makes it return to its normal RButton functions.

It sounds simple enough in my head but I can't make anything work for the life of me .__.

So I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a hotkey that listens for the `a` key. You should be able to find all the information needed in the docs here - http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Next you need to create your `Rbutton` hotkey and make it conditional to detect if `a` has been pressed. To do that you use the [`#if` directive](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm). Make sure you're updated to the [latest version of AHK](http://ahkscript.org/download/) otherwise this directive won't work.

Your final code would look something like this:

```
; Init toggle var as "0"
changeNextPress := 0

; Toggle the variable to "1"
; The ~ symbols allows the "a" key be captured without blocking it
~a::
    changeNextPress := 1
return

; Only activate this key if the toggle variable is "1"
#if (changeNextPress == 1)
    Rbutton::
        ; Since we only want one press, toggle the variable back to "0" again
        changeNextPress := 0
        Send, {LButton}
    return
#if
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the insight, was really helpful. However, after some research I found that "Send{}" doesn't work properly with some programs and/or games. Is there a way to do it with _Rbutton::Lbutton_ and then reverse it back?

Comment: @ZekeFlynn Not really, you could try using different send methods though, like `SendInput` or `SendPlay`. You can read about them [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm).